# Canvas: fit drawing to canvas size without changing the coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Let's say we're dynamically drawing a fractal on a canvas. Since we don't know how big the fractal is going to be, at some point we'd need to scale (zoom out) the canvas to fit our fractal in there.

How do we do that? How to scale it:

1. Properly, so that it perfectly fits the drawing we have, and
2. So that the coordinates stay the same, and our fractal calculation doesn't need to use the scale value (meaning, `return x`, not `return x * scale`, if possible)
3. What if the fractal grows in all directions and we have negative values?

See the tiny example below.

```js
var $canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx     = $canvas.getContext('2d'),
    lastX   = 0,
    lastY   = 0;

    drawLoop();


function drawLoop() {
    var newX = lastX + 30,
        newY = lastY + 30;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(newX, newY);
    ctx.stroke();

    lastX = newX;
    lastY = newY;

    setTimeout(drawLoop, 1000);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="100" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Recall that the canvas has both an intrinsic size and a displayed size. A million pixel canvas of 1000 x 1000 could be displayed at the size of 100 x 100 - like any other image resource. You could create a new canvas, copy the existing one into it and then continue working with your recently-resized drawing area.

Comment: Well... you just update a bouding box of your drawing, at every new coords generated, `bbox.left = Math.min( bbox.left, newcoord.x); bbox.right = Math.max( bbox.right, newcoord.x); bbox.top = ` etc. and in a more clever way, but you get the idea. But without seeing your code, we can't really help you.

Comment: @Kaiido there's the snippet in the description. Run it, and you'll see a line going outside of the canvas.

Comment: Well if that's really "the code", it's quite easy to update the bounding box...

Answer (score 5):

You can scale, translate, and rotate the drawing coordinates via the canvas transform.

If you have the min and max coordinates of your drawing

Example:

```
const min = {x: 100, y: 200};
const max = {x: 10009, y: 10000};
```

You can make it fit the canvas as follows

```
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

// get a scale to best fit the canvas
const scale = Math.min(width / (max.x - min.x), height / (max.y - min.y));

// get a origin so that the drawing is centered on the canvas
const top = (height - (max.y - min.y)) / 2;
const left = (width - (max.x - min.x)) / 2;

// set the transform so that you can draw to the canvas
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, left, top);

// draw something
ctx.strokeRect(min.x, min.y, max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);
```

If you do not know the size of the drawing area at the start then you will need to save drawing coordinates as you go. When the min and max change you then recalculate the transform, clear the canvas and redraw. There is no other way if you do not know the size at the beginning.